# Не работает counter при скролле страницы вниз

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, counter

Не работает jquery spincrement при скролле вниз. Работает только когда просто обновляешь страницу.Нужно сделать чтобы только когда скролишь вниз.

```html
<a name="counter"></a>
<div class="snumber">
    <div class="snumber__inner">
        <div class="snumber__element">
            <p class="snumber__number">4231</p>
            <p class="snumber__title">Наименование</p>
        </div>
        <div class="snumber__element">
            <p class="snumber__number">500</p>
            <p class="snumber__title">Наименование</p>
        </div>
        <div class="snumber__element">
            <p class="snumber__number">152</p>
            <p class="snumber__title">Наименование</p>
        </div>
                <div class="snumber__element">
            <p class="snumber__number">125</p>
            <p class="snumber__title">Наименование</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var show = true;
    var countbox = ".snumber__inner";
    $(window).on("scroll load resize", function () {
        if (!show) return true; // Отменяем показ анимации, если она уже была выполнена
        var w_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // Количество пикселей на которое была прокручена страница
        var e_top = $(countbox).offset().top; // Расстояние от блока со счетчиками до верха всего документа
        var w_height = $(window).height(); // Высота окна браузера
        var d_height = $(document).height(); // Высота всего документа
        var e_height = $(countbox).outerHeight(); // Полная высота блока со счетчиками
        if (w_top + 500 >= e_top || w_height + w_top == d_height || e_height + e_top < w_height) {
            $('.snumber__number').css('opacity', '1');
            $('.snumber__number').spincrement({
                thousandSeparator: "",
                duration: 1200
            });

            show = false;
        }
    });

});
```

```css
   
.snumber__number {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените событие scroll на wheel.
Вот так:

```
$(window).on("wheel load resize", function () {
```

Comment: Почему-то не помогло

Comment: нажмите на F12 и во вкладке Console посмотрите есть ли ошибки

Comment: Есть, но это другие ошибки связанные с картинками т.к в папке у меня их нет.

Comment: У меня также работает когда перезагружаешь страницу в зоне видимости она работает, а если с начала header прокручивать вниз она же не прокручивается

Comment: вам надо когда колесико мыши крутится вниз менялся текст верно?

Comment: Да, чтобы анимация на цифрах была

Comment: ну так уберите if (!show) return true;